# How do I match all occurrences of a specific pattern in Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I cant find regex expression of  <#anystring#>?

Ex: <#sda#> or <#32dwdwwd#> or any of string between <# and #>

I tried `"<#[^<#]+#>"` but this has outputted only the first occurrence.

```
        string sample = "\n\n<#sample01#> jus some words <#sample02#> <#sample03#> just some words ";
        Match match = Regex.Match(sample, "<#[^<#]+#>");
        if (match.Success)
        {
            foreach (Capture capture in match.Captures)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(capture.Value);
            }
        }
```

Comment: "<#[^<#]+#>" this has outputted only the first occurrence. Actually I am not good at regex. Just started.

Comment: Please edit your question when you have additional information. Your regex looks good, so it is a matter of how you call your regex and treat the result. Show your c# code (By an edit of your question!)

Comment: @Carlos that's better, so now your problem becomes apparent. Please show the code you are using to use the regex, you probably just need to tweak some options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `match()` method. Try reading the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and you will see, that it returns only the first match.

Try the [`matches()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method instead, it returns a [MatchCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

It would look something like this (careful, not tested written directly here)

```
string sample = "\n\n<#sample01#> jus some words <#sample02#> <#sample03#> just some words ";
    MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(sample, "<#(.*?)#>");
    foreach (Match m in mc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. As I said  I am really new at regex. started 20 min ago. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this one , it should work

UPDATED

`<#(.*?)#>`

- The dot is any character except new line (\n).
- The * means 0 or more.
- The ? is used to make it ungreedy.

[source here](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/)

Comment: Have you seen the edit of the question? This is not a matter of the used regex.

Comment: No still the first occurrence only. Am I missing something.

Comment: I am testing it at http://regexhero.net/tester/and I get 2 matching groups. Could you add the code you are using to the question